# Find all slides with a specific Tags.Value and delete them

Tags: vba, powerpoint

New to VBA. I have a large PPT with over 150 slides, and I have run a VBA macro to tag them (SlidesA ... SlidesF) into tag "groupings". I have a userform with a bunch of check boxes to select slide groupings the user wants keep. After selecting the groupings the user wants to keep they click an OK button. I have some code (below) to find slides that are not checked and delete them based on Tags.Value, and keep the rest. But for some reason it's not deleting all the slides, it's just deleting like 4 of them in SlidesA group.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

' Slide.Tag has .Name and .Value parameters

If chkSlidesA = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesA" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

If chkSlidesB = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesB" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

If chkSlidesC = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesC" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

If chkSlidesD = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesD" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

If chkSlidesE = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesE" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

If chkSlidesF = False Then
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Value(i) = "SlidesF" Then
            s.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
Else

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

I have verified the slides are tagged with the right values by running some VBA to read the tags and display a MsgBox to display the tag value.

I'm trying to understand why it isn't deleting all the slides.

Comment: Try reversing the order of slide traversal / deletion

Comment: You have made the classic newbie mistake when deleting items from a collection.  When you delete item 2, what was item 3 automatically becomes Item 2.  But the control valiable managed by VBA doesn't know this and increments to 3, but item 3 is now what was item 4, so you have skipped over an item.  The only way you can safely delete from a colection is to iterate the collection in reverse.  This means you can't do a For Each, you have to to a for next using Count -1 to 1.

Comment: Yea, my original idea was to just delete sections and I noticed it was doing the whole "3 becomes 2" and as it iterated through it was deleting the wrong section IDs... It didn't occur to me that it was doing it here as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So other people can see the revised solution that worked for me, here is my final working version of the code:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Dim concatSlidesAF As String
    concatSlidesAF = IIf(chkSlidesA, "", "A") & IIf(chkSlidesB, "", "B" & _
                     IIf(chkSlidesC, "", "C") & IIf(chkSlidesD, "", "D") & _
                     IIf(chkSlidesE, "", "E") & IIf(chkSlidesF, "", "F")
    
    If Len(concatSlidesAF) = 0 Then
        GoTo ES
    Else
        concatSlidesAF = "Slides[" & concatSlidesAF & "]"
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Item(i)
                For j = 1 To .Tags.Count
                    If .Tags.Value(j) Like concatSlidesAF Then
                        .Delete
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End With
        Next i
    End With

Call DeleteEmptySections

ES:
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I also included a Sub to find and delete any sections that no longer contained any slides:

```
Sub DeleteEmptySections()
    Dim lSP As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For lSP = .Count To 1 Step -1
            If .SlidesCount(lSP) = 0 Then .Delete lSP, True
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

@freeflow's + my comment translated into code

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Dim concatSlidesAF As String
    concatSlidesAF = IIf(chkSlidesA, "A", "") & IIf(chkSlidesB, "B", "") & _
                     IIf(chkSlidesC, "C", "") & IIf(chkSlidesD, "D", "") & _
                     IIf(chkSlidesE, "E", "") & IIf(chkSlidesF, "F", "")
    
    If Len(concatSlidesAF) = 0 Then
        GoTo ES
    Else
        concatSlidesAF = "Slides[" & concatSlidesAF & "]"
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Item(i)
                For j = 1 To .Tags.Count
                    If .Tags.Value(j) Like concatSlidesAF Then
                        .Delete
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End With
        Next i
    End With
ES:
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I used `concatSlidesAF` just so I can condense the code a bit.

Comment: I've tried this code but it's not working for me. Question: in your example you have this: `IIf(chkSlidesA, "A", "")`. What are the two strings wrapped in double quotes denoting? Is that the Tag Name and Tag Value parameters? I'm trying to match on the tag `.Value`. I've tried moving the tag value to the second set of double quotes but it still didn't work.

Comment: `IIf (chkSlidesA, "A", "")` means if `chkSlidesA` is `TRUE` return string A, otherwise return empty string. This is used for checking Tag values. Try doing `IIf (chkSlidesA.value <> False, "A", "")`.  If you have selected chkSlidesA and chkSlidesB checkboxs for example, concatSlidesAF will be equal to `Slides[AB]` and this is used in like statement.

Comment: Example of using Like: `"SlidesD" Like "Slides[ABCD]"` is `True` but `"SlidesF" Like "Slides[ABCD]"` is `False`. I hope that intention behind using IIFs is clear now.

Comment: Ok, I figured out why this wasn't working for me. I had to move the "A", "B", etc. to the FALSE part like this: ```concatSlidesAF = IIf(chkSlidesA, "", "A")``` because I want to trigger if the chkSlidesA is NOT checked (i.e. the user doesn't want those slides, so delete them). I was also using different Tag names, and was having trouble with the ```Like``` operator matching, so the only way I could get it to work was to actually use these tag names (SlidesA, SlidesB, etc.). But it works.