# highlight a cell that contains a string in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to highlight a cell that contains any of the string in a certain column. It work but i also want to delete the entire row of cell that is not highlighted.

```
Dim Cells, cella As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim uB, lB As Integer



Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Cells = ws.Range("J2:J100")
myArray = Array("ALM", "NYF", "NED", "NND", "NYW", "PAF", "PAD", "FLM", "ALD", "AZR", 
"CAR", "FLK", "NIO")

uB = UBound(myArray)
lB = LBound(myArray)

For Each cell In Cells
 For i = lB To uB
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, myArray(i)) > 0 Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    Else
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
   Next i
Next cell
```

Comment: Using for each on a collection + deleting elements of that collection will never give you correct result. Check feeflow's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248409/find-all-slides-with-a-specific-tags-value-and-delete-them

Comment: You may want to change you variable name from `Cells` to something else (`Cells` refers to all cells on the sheet)

Comment: indeed @milo5m; based on @feeflow comment, i decided to create new sub just for deleting the cells without highlight. and it worked! thanks!

Comment: also, as suggested by @cybernetic.nomad var name is changed.